# angularjs service uncaught syntax error unexpected identifier

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Angularjs service which is returning my json data from web service is creating error uncaught syntax error unexpected identifier at return statement.

this is my angularjs service-

```
        app.factory('GetProjectService', function ($http, $q) {
            return {
               getProject: function(str) {
               $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:19342/api/Search/GetAllProjects',
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                     }).then(function(response) {
                        if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                            return response.data;
                        } else {
                            return $q.reject(response.data);
                        }
                    }, function(response) {
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    });
               }
        };

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

$q is not used properly in your code. Please refer following code snippet -

```
  app.factory('GetProjectService', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
           getProject: function(str) {
             var deferred = $q.defer();

             $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: 'http://localhost:19342/api/Search/GetAllProjects',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                   }).then(function(response) {
                      deferred.resolve(response.data);
                  }, function(response) {
                      deferred.reject(response.data);
                  });
             return deferred.promise;
           }
    };

});
```

But when you are $http, there is no need to use $q as $http returns the promise obj. Here is another way of using $http in services -

```
  app.factory('GetProjectService', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
           getProject: function(str) {

             return $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: 'http://localhost:19342/api/Search/GetAllProjects',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                   });

           }

    };

});
```

Comment: `$q.reject` is a valid method of the `$q` service. It creates a promise that is rejected with a specified value. For more information, see [AngularJS $q API Reference - $q.reject](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject)

Comment: Yes, it returns promise, but the code was written in such a way that getProject function is not returning anything, we should return promise by either ways mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The `getProject` was missing a `return` statement.

```
app.factory('GetProjectService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getProject: function getProject(str) {
            //RETURN http promise 
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:19342/api/Search/GetAllProjects',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
                if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                    return response.data;
                } else {
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                }
            }, function onReject(response) {
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            });

        }
    };

});
```

There needs to be a `return` statement at each level of the function hierarchy. The factory needs a `return` statement, the `getProject` function needs a `return` statement, and the `onSuccess` and `onReject` functions need either a `return` or `throw` statement.